# MUI Data Grid horizontal scrolling (responsiveness) is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, mui-datatable

I created a Data Grid table with 10 columns. It looks great on big screens but when I squeeze it below 1380 px, I expect to see a horizontal bar scrolling but it looks terrible.

I don't want to switch to another library and just need to fix this horizontal scrolling problem. In the docs, it works perfectly. But I use renderCell and I think that cause the problem. But couldn't solve it still.

**Here is how it looks like in big screens:**

[image]

**Here how it looks like at 1303 px:**

[image]

**And here on mobile sizes it can scroll but its sequeezed a lot and looks terrible:**

[image]

I tried many suggestions on stack but couldn't find any solution still.
Here is my styled DataGrid props:

```
    <DataGridStyled
    rows={getRowData()}
    autoHeight
    rowHeight={80}
    columns={columns}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 15, 30, 100]}
    pageSize={pageSize}
    onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
    checkboxSelection
    disableSelectionOnClick
    pagination
    scrollbarSize={50}
  />
```

**Here is the 5th column (I used renderCell maybe its because of this?):**

```
{
  field: 'bloodPressure',
  headerName: 'BP (mmHg)',
  headerAlign: 'center',
  align: 'center',
  type: 'string',
  flex: 1,
  editable: false,
  valueGetter: (params) =>
    params?.row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys === undefined
      ? null
      : params?.row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys,
  renderCell: (params) => {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
        followCursor
        title={
          params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDate === undefined
            ? 'No measurement'
            : moment(params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDate).fromNow()
        }
      >
        <Box
          display="flex"
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          width={'60%'}
          bgcolor={params.row?.bloodPressure?.riskColor}
          borderRadius={1}
          py={0.3}
        >
          <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="black">
            {params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys === undefined ||
            params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDia === undefined
              ? '--'
              : `${params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys?.toFixed(
                  0
                )}/${params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDia?.toFixed(0)}`}
          </Typography>
          <Typography
            variant="subtitle1"
            color="black"
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              alignItems: 'center'
            }}
          >
            {params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys === undefined &&
            params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDia === undefined ? null : params
                .row?.bloodPressure?.lastSys +
                params.row?.bloodPressure?.lastDia >
              params.row?.bloodPressure?.previousSys +
                params.row?.bloodPressure?.previousDia ? (
              <ArrowUpwardIcon
                sx={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  lineHeight: 1.75,
                  height: '100%'
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <ArrowDownwardIcon
                sx={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  lineHeight: 1.75,
                  height: '100%'
                }}
              />
            )}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }
},
```

Comment: Did you figure out to fix this?

Comment: Yes. you need to give minWidth to each column & remove flex: 1

Comment: Thanks @OğuzhanYıldırım ! Adding `minWidth` to every column makes it work. It didn't work even without the `flex` values. Do you know why you have to set a `min-width` to every column?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `flex: 1`, you need to remove that.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.